# Coding In AMPL Software

Tags: ampl

How can I start with a specific city under a set of cities, rather than using x[i,j]
I want to write such constraint x[1,2] + x[2,5] = 1

Moreover, how can I start from i=2, j=2 rather than start with i,j =1

Thanks,
Haidar

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Can you please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I mean if I have such sets: set S;  set L;      S=1,..s      L=1,....l.     Here in my constraint, I do not want to use the whole set. Only for example s= 2 and l= 3 or I want to start from s= 2,...,s with excluding s =1. How can I do that with Ampl?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write such constraint x[1,2] + x[2,5] = 1

```
s.t. c1: x[1,2]+x[2,5]=1;
```

> how can I start from i=2, j=2 rather than start with i,j =1

Define index sets that don't have 1 in them. For instance, if you have

```
set S := 1..s;
```

then you could either do:

```
set S_2 := 2..s;
```

or:

```
set S_2 := S diff {2};
```

and then create a constraint indexed on S_2.

Comment: @Haidar Great! If this answered your question, please click the "accept" button so other users know that the question doesn't require further responses.